# How to find an index of a substring within an array of strings in iOS swift

Tags: arrays, swift, string, indexing

I currently have an array of strings separated by a new line character. I need to have the index of a specific element that begins with these 16 characters("dayTime" is the variable name). I know this will only occur once in the array. I created a second array that is the first array that is truncated to the first 16 characters of each element and I get nil for my index when running.

```
let newlineChars = NSCharacterSet.newlines
let lineArray = contents.components(separatedBy: newlineChars).filter{!$0.isEmpty}

let array2 = lineArray.prefix(16)

let indexOfdayTime = array2.firstIndex(of: dayTime)
print ("This is the INDEX OF day time: ", indexOfdayTime)
```

I expect and index value not nil.

Comment: FYI - Do not use `NSCharacterSet` in Swift. Use `CharacterSet`.

Comment: *"I created a second array that is the first array that is truncated to the first 16 characters of each element"*. No, the code you posted creates a new array containing the first 16 elements of the original array. Print `array2` and you will see your issue.

Comment: In general, please show actual code. Posting your code with letting us know what `contents` is and what `dayTime` is, is not a helpful or productive way to ask a question.

Comment: Alright I understand how it is wrong now, so thank you for that. But How do I create a second array, where each element is the first 16 characters of the element in the original array at the same index?

Answer (score 0):

I would use this line to find the string

```
let indexOfdayTime = array2.firstIndex { $0.starts(with: dayTime) }
```

If you still want to get first 16 characters from each line you could use `map`

```
let array2 = lineArray.map { $0.prefix(16)}
```